# How to configure FLINK state server ip?

Tags: networking, streaming

I can't find an configuration item refers to state server ip.

I've tried to modify the `jobmanager.rpc.address` to `0.0.0.0`, but I still can't access state server with ip `172.16.150.172` which is my local ip address. It still bind to the `127.0.0.1`.

It's all my configuration items.
[image: it's my full configuration]

state server startup logging
[image: state server startup logging]

It's my local ip address.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please share below results.
 1. `netstat -tulpn` 
 2. are you able to telnet 9069 with your instance ip **172.16.150.172** ?

Make sure that all nodes in your cluster have the same **jobmanager.rpc.address** configured.

nano flink-conf.yaml Add this line:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: 172.16.150.172
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/config.html